# Echo another command in CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hello Everyone I'm new to any kind of scripting but I'm slowly learning. Here is my issue, I'm trying to echo a line in cmd that I'm assuming is picking it up as another command. I want to

echo $cmdOutput = ($env:COMPUTERNAME -replace "TEMP", "RUSS" | Out-String).Trim(). However, this is the error that it is giving me when trying echo it.

C:\Temp>echo $cmdOutput = ($env:COMPUTERNAME -replace "TEMP", "RUSS" | Out-String).Trim()
'Out-String).Trim' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I just want it to echo it whole code back because eventually I'm going to have this appended to a .txt file however I need a little help to get over this obstacle. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just to clarify, you are aware that in a PowerShell script, ```$cmdOutput = ($env:COMPUTERNAME -replace "TEMP", "RUSS" | Out-String).Trim()``` is a command, and in a batch file just a string; aren't you? If you are trying to `echo` it to a `.ps1` file, you'd need to use ```Echo $cmdOutput = ($env:COMPUTERNAME -replace "TEMP", "RUSS" ^| Out-String).Trim()```, to escape the special character `|`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is a powershell script command however I just want it to come out as a string in a batch. Basically that command will get echo'ed and will get appended to a simple .txt file. However, thank you for that because that did exactly what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical bar has a special meaning in cmd (pipe character).
You can prevent echo from interpreting this character as command-character by escaping it with a caret.

Answer (score -1):

you have a problem with

> (Out-String).Trim()

try this command in powershell

```
echo $cmdOutput = ($env:COMPUTERNAME -replace "TEMP", "RUSS" | Out- String).TrimStart()
```